# pymilvus search embeddings by JSON

Tags: python, database, milvus

I'm using pymilvus 2.2.13.
I have a JSON field in my collection:
metadata: `{"firld_a": "x", "list_field": ["A", "B", "C"]}`
I want to get all the embeddings that have A in their list field,
I tried to use json_contains like the following example:

```py
self.collection.query(
     expr=f'json_contains(metadata["list_field"],"A")', 
     output_fields=['metadata']
)
```

and got a milvus error, how can I get the requested result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_contains_any` instead of `json_contains`. Note that `json_contains` regards the value of each key as a whole, while `json_contains_any` checks the elements.

For details, refer to [Advanced Operators](https://milvus.io/docs/use-json-fields.md#Advanced-Operators) here.

Comment: thanks, I'm still getting the exact same error - cannot parse expression: json_contains_any(.. it might be because of the structure of the field?